# Do iOS/Android require minimum OS support for apps?

Tags: android, ios

So I found [This](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) on android, but it seems more or less like good practice than a requirement. I couldn't find much on whether or not there is a minimum requirement for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

> Setting the Deployment Target
>   The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on. For example, the lowest available setting for iPad apps is iOS 4.3.
>
> There are several strategies for choosing the deployment target when developing your app. Each version of an OS includes features and capabilities not present in earlier versions. As new versions are published, some users may upgrade immediately, while other users may wait before moving to the latest version. You can target the latest version, taking full advantage of all the new features but limiting the app to only users running the latest version. Or you can target an earlier version, making your app available to more users but limiting the features you can use in the app. Another approach is to target an earlier version but use weak linking to determine at runtime whether later version features are available before using them.
>
> For details on weak linking, read Weak Linking and Apple Frameworks in SDK Compatibility Guide.
>
> To set the target version
>
> In the project navigator, select the project and your target to display the project editor.
>   Click General and, if necessary, click the disclosure triangle next to Deployment Info to reveal the settings.
>   Choose the version you want to target from the Deployment Target pop-up menu.
>
> Note: The SDK version, not the deployment target, determines which features you can use in an app. If the SDK you’re using to build the app is more recent than the app’s deployment target, Xcode displays build warnings when it detects that your app is using a feature that’s unavailable in the deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

There is a field called "Deployment target" in your project's settings, here you must enter the minimum version of OS that supporting your app.

Comment: No I knew about that - I just didn't know if iOS or Android made a minimum supported version

Answer (score 1):

Deployment target is minimum version

[image: Deployment Target]